# Thingsboard CE mobile application Device Dashboard not picking up entity context

Tags: thingsboard

I have configured a **Mobile Dashboard** for a **Device Profile**. In the TB provided mobile application built navigating to a device from the Devices listing does not pick the right device context, instead land on either the default one or empty dashboard.

The Mobile Dashboard configured for the Device Profile **rmu**.

[image]

As per the [docs](https://thingsboard.io/docs/mobile/device-dashboard/), I have configured the Mobile Dashboard to use the Entity from Dashboard State alias for the widget datasource.

[image]

I have built the thingsboard provided mobile (flutter) application.

In the app, if I navigate to a device from the Devices listing, the dashboard does not pick the selected device context, instead land on either the default one or empty dashboard as depicted below.

[image]

Help me with this. What am I missing?